# how to get first,last and other values of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a object like this, which contain location and stopover values.

`[{"location":"8, Nehru Nagar, Ambavadi, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380015, India","stopover":true},

{"location":"CISF Cargo Road, Sardar Vallabhbhai Patel International Airport (AMD), Hansol, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 382475, India","stopover":true},

{"location":"Sardar Patel Ring Road, Sughad, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 382424, India","stopover":true},

{"location":"Kudasan Road, Urjanagar 1, Kudasan, Gujarat 382421, India","stopover":true},

  {"location":"Gujarat State HIghway 141, Alampur, Gujarat 382355, India","stopover":true},

  {"location":"Hanuman Ji Mandir Bus Stop, Dabhoda, Gujarat 382355, India","stopover":true}]`

so my question is
(1) how to get first value of location as start destination?
(2) how to get last value of location as end destination?
(3) how to get other values of location as waypoints?

[see this,how i pushed value in waypts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380203/old-value-of-array-replace-by-new-value-of-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got there is an array of objects. The individual items in the array can be accessed by numeric index, and then the individual properties of each object can be accessed by name. So:

```
// assuming waypts is the variable/function
// argument referring to the array:

var firstLoc = waypts[0].location;
var lastLoc = waypts[waypts.length-1].location;
```

Bearing in mind that JS array indexes start at 0, you can get the location at position *n* in the array with

```
waypts[n].location
```

And of course a standard for loop lets you iterate over all the waypoints in the array:

```
for(var j=0; j < waypts.length; j++) {
    alert(waypts[j].location);
}
```

You'd access the *stopover* property in the same way:

```
waypts[j].stopover
```

Comment: thank you very much.it's work.but don't understand that i use `waypts.push({location:add,stopover:true});` to create array then how it become  array of objects?.

Comment: `{location:add,stopover:true}` is an object. So each item you push into the array is an object.

Answer (score 1):

That's not just an object, it's an array and so the items can be accessed by index.

So if that object is assigned to a variable

```
  places = [{"location":"8, Nehru Nagar, Ambavadi, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380015, India","stopover":true},
{"location":"CISF Cargo Road, Sardar Vallabhbhai Patel International Airport (AMD), Hansol, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 382475, India","stopover":true},
{"location":"Sardar Patel Ring Road, Sughad, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 382424, India","stopover":true},
{"location":"Kudasan Road, Urjanagar 1, Kudasan, Gujarat 382421, India","stopover":true},
{"location":"Gujarat State HIghway 141, Alampur, Gujarat 382355, India","stopover":true},
{"location":"Hanuman Ji Mandir Bus Stop, Dabhoda, Gujarat 382355, India","stopover":true}];
```

You can access

```
 places[0]; // first
 places[places.length -1]; // last
```

and iterate using

```
 for ( var i = 1; i < places.length - 2 ; i++){
    places[i]; // access to waypoints
 }
```

Comment: i alert this :`alert(typeof waypts);` and it display it's an object.

Comment: @DS9: json = JavaScript **Object** Notation

Comment: [see this,how i pushed value in waypts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380203/old-value-of-array-replace-by-new-value-of-array)

Comment: arrays are objects, so typeof is misleading you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: In your code you have  var waypts=[]; that's an array. Please try my answer.

Comment: it's alert [object Object]

Answer (score 1):

A basic example :

```
var a = [{p:1},{p:2},{p:3},{p:4}];
/* first */  a[0];            // Object {p: 1}
/* last */   a[a.length - 1]; // Object {p: 4}
/* second */ a[1];            // Object {p: 2}
             a[0].p;          // 1
```

Don't rely on `typeof` :

```
typeof new Array // "object"
typeof new Object // "object"
```

Comment: thnaks for spending your time.